# How to return error from async funtion returning Task<T>

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a basic asynchronous method in one class, which returns an object.

In some of the flows it may fail and I want to report it back.

But I can only return the object.

I tried nullable object, but got the error:

> MyObject must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

I assume I can use exception, but I wanted something simpler in the calling function.

I also cannot use `ref` or `out` in async methods.

Is there a way to report back some kind of true/false of success or failure?

```
public static async Task<MyObject> getObject()
{
    if (NotOkFromSomeReason())
    {
          //Not sure what to do here
    }
    return await myDataBase.FindAsync(something);
}
```

I call it using:

```
  MyObject object = await getObject();
  // I want something simple as if(object)...
```

Comment: Why you can't prepare own class? F.e. Result that holds value and other needed data?

Comment: The error basically tells you, that the type `MyObject` is already nullable. I guess, it's a `class` (and not a `struct`, like `int`, `long` or the like). So you could just `return null;` and then check `if (myObject == null) { /* ... */ } `.

Comment: @nopeflow - I can. I just hoped from some simple solution.

Comment: how you define `MyObject`?

Comment: @corak I don't know how I missed it. You are absolutely right. I over complicated myself for no reason. Please post it as answer.

Comment: @IgalS. if you mark your function `async` then you can return `null` directly, but then you'd have to `await` on `FindAsync` (the code you posted would not compile, you can't use `async` and return a `Task<MyObject>`, you need to `await` on that task)

Comment: @Jcl - You are right. I see somebody already edit and fixed the question for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If returning `null` is an option, you can do:

```
public static Task<MyObject> getObject()
{
  if (NotOkFromSomeReason())
  {
    return Task.FromResult<MyObject>(null);
  }
  return myDataBase.FindAsync(something);
}
```

*PS: I'm supposing there's no other code which uses `await` in this function, so I've removed `async`. Otherwise you can just use the `async` qualifier and return `null` directly. Since it's returning `Task` objects, it's still awaitable from the outside*

Then you could check for `null` outside:

```
MyObject myObject = await getObject();
if(myObject == null)
{
}
```

This will only work if `null` is not a possible "correct" result

You could otherwise use exceptions

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz actually, you were right, if using `async` I would return `null`, but this method didn't need `async` for anything since it's not awaiting. I've edited to remove the `async` and add the remark

Comment: Since I have `await FindAsync` I can return `null` directly as suggested above. That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @IgalS. note that using just an `await` as the last instruction of a method returning `Task<T>` is generally unneeded and will introduce some (not a lot, but some) performance costs. If you are not doing anything after your `await` (just returning the value), then just don't mark the method `async` and directly return your `Task` object so it's only awaited from the calling method. I supposed this was some sample code and that method is doing something else, that's why I added the remark

Answer (score 7):

Just wrap it into yet another class that will return both desired instance & status code - like:

```
public class StatusReport
{
    public boolean Ok { get; set; }
    public MyObject Instance { get; set; }
}

public static async Task<StatusReport> getObject()
{
  if (NotOkForSomeReason())
  {
    return new StatusReport { Ok = false };
  }
  return new StatusReport { Ok = true, Instance = await myDataBase.FindAsync(something) };
}
```

Comment: This is a solution. But I was looking for something simpler.